# How to troubleshoot "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, dataset

how can I troubleshoot "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."?
I am using a combobox, to retrieve the price and discount price of the service, If I select an item in combobox3 once, error will not occur, but if I select a item again in combobox3, "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types." will occur..

here is my code

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    ds = getPrice(arr(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex), ComboBox3.Text)


    If ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows.Count - 1

            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows(i).Item(0))
            TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows(i).Item(1))

        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

this is my query

```
 Public Function getPrice(ByVal serviceId As String, ByVal breedSize As String)

    If breedSize = "Small Breed" Then
        sqlStr = "Select price_small_breed, discount_small_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
    ElseIf breedSize = "Medium Breed" Then
        sqlStr = "Select price_medium_breed, discount_medium_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
    ElseIf breedSize = "Big Breed" Then
        sqlStr = "Select price_big_breed, discount_big_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
    End If

    ds.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con.ConnectionString)
    da.Fill(ds, "getPrice")


    Return ds

End Function
```

here is the image

[image]

what could be the caused of having this problem?

Comment: What is the point of iterating the rows, if you are assigning to a singular set of text boxes?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox1.Text = If(ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows(i).Item(0) Is DBNull.Value, "", Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows(i).Item(0)).ToString()) 
TextBox2.Text = If(ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows(i).Item(0) Is DBNull.Value, "", Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables("getPrice").Rows(i).Item(1)).ToString())
```

Comment: Yeah, if there is no data in the dataset, it doesn't matter what you try to convert it to.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the specific query statement that was executed in GetPrice against the database, you will see that at least one of the rows has a null value at the ordinal position you are reading.

It is likely that serviceID (note the caps) is not the value you are assuming it is.

Answer (score 0):

What do want to happen if there is a NULL value in the database? If it would be acceptable to use some value instead, e.g. zero, you could modify the query like

```
sqlStr = "Select COALESCE(price_small_breed, 0), COALESCE(discount_small_breed, 0) From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " & serviceId & ""
```

Answer (score -4):

my answer is this.. I declare new dataset, I do not used the dataset from the top of my code

```
Public Function getPrice(ByVal serviceId As String, ByVal breedSize As String) As DataSet

        Dim dsa As New DataSet


        If breedSize = "Small Breed" Then
            sqlStr = "Select price_small_breed, discount_small_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
        ElseIf breedSize = "Medium Breed" Then
            sqlStr = "Select price_medium_breed, discount_medium_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
        ElseIf breedSize = "Big Breed" Then
            sqlStr = "Select price_big_breed, discount_big_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
        End If

        dsa.Clear()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con.ConnectionString)
        da.Fill(dsa, "getPrice")

        Return dsa

    End Function
```

this is my previous code..

```
Public Function getPrice(ByVal serviceId As String, ByVal breedSize As String)

    If breedSize = "Small Breed" Then
        sqlStr = "Select price_small_breed, discount_small_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
    ElseIf breedSize = "Medium Breed" Then
        sqlStr = "Select price_medium_breed, discount_medium_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
    ElseIf breedSize = "Big Breed" Then
        sqlStr = "Select price_big_breed, discount_big_breed From tblServicePrice Where service_id = " + serviceId + ""
    End If

    ds.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con.ConnectionString)
    da.Fill(ds, "getPrice")


    Return ds

End Function
```

Comment: It works, that's why I'm the one who answer my question @StingyJack, there answer is not working...

Comment: who are you to say that thing to me? Don't say that thing to me because you don't even posting your solution to my problem...

Comment: @StingyJack - sure it makes sense, it just doesn't answer the question. uer188228 has found a workaround - just don't select the NULL columns. Of course, if there's ever an unexpected null then the situation will be right where it was left.

Comment: @StingyJack- what is the purpose of stackoverflow? stackoverflow is existing to help other people to pursue their career in programming, to help other people in their problem in programming...

Comment: Ask a question, work through and get an answer. You basically asked a question, ignored all other answers that explain why you get this error and how to fix it, and chose one of your own that does not even solve the issue you originally posted. Now, this lame bits of information is going to sit around for someone else to read and be confused by, forever.